# window.open and URLs with anchor

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a javascript application which - among a lot of other controls - contains a button. When clicking this button I need to open a new window with an URL based on some selections made in the control and this I have made with a simple code

```
window.open(myurl);
```

The generated URL could end up like this "domain.xx/page#anchor", this works as expected in FF, but IE totally ignores the anchor - the page is not correct positioned and the anchor is not even shown in the URL.

I can solve this writing my code like this

```
var test = window.open();
test.location.href = myurl;
```

the codes opens the window as expected, but inserting the URL and loading the page is very slow and therefore gives a bad user experience.

Any ideas how to make this better?

Comment: Why don't you use the parameters? `test = window.open(myurl);` . Does that make it any faster?

Comment: btw: what you call a "bookmark", I know as "anchor".

Comment: Armin - I think "it" has many names, but correct, anchor is probably more correct :)

OptimusCrime - As I wrote, using window.open(myurl) does not transfer the anchor to the page in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I targeted IE (which is quite a while ago) the trick was to have a

```
<form action="http://domain.xx/page#bookmark" method="get" target="_blank" name="foo"></form>
```

and do

```
forms['foo'].submit()
```

on click.

Comment: You don't need to submit the form with javascript. You could add a `<button type="submit">Click me</button>`. You just need to manipulate the action.

Comment: That may or may not work - I never checked if an unnamed submit button will not create a spurious GET parameter across all browsers. Interesting question in its own right!

Comment: If I remember correct target is not valid in all DTD and I have to provide valid code - at the same time I cannot use a form-tag as it could end up giving problems on the pages where my application will be included. My application does not make use of input, select, button etc - only div, span, img etc because of the same reason.